The ID is not taken from another table
enter image description here
I checked the postponement, and realized that the id of OrderDetail is assigned 0, which may be why I don't know, since I checked the id has such a string in the migration as
id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),

I want to write an ID in carID from another table, the data in it is filled in, everything is fine with it, carId = el.clothes.IdClothes
I thought the error was that the ID was not created in Order, but that was not the case

Внутреннее исключение 1:SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_OrderDetail_Clothes_clothesIdClothes". The conflict occurred in database "ShopClothes", table "dbo.Clothes", column 'IdClothes'.
`public void createOrder(Order order){order.orderTime = DateTime.Now;appDbContent.Order.Add(order);appDbContent.SaveChanges();

var items = shopCart.listShopItems;

foreach (var el in items)
{
    var orderDetail = new OrderDetail()
    {
        carId = el.clothes.IdClothes,
        orderId = order.id,
        price = el.clothes.price
    };
    appDbContent.OrderDetail.Add(orderDetail);
}
appDbContent.SaveChanges();
}





public class Order
 {
     public int id { get; set; }
 [Display(Name = "Введите адрес")]
 [StringLength(25)]
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Заполните адрес")]
 public string address { get; set; }


 [BindNever]
 public DateTime orderTime { get; set; }
 public List<OrderDetail> orderDetails { get; set; }

}
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int orderId { get; set; }
    public int carId { get; set; }
    public uint price { get; set; }
    public virtual Clothes clothes { get; set; }
    public virtual Order order { get; set; }
}

public class Clothes
{
    [Key]
    public int IdClothes { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }
    public ushort price { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public bool avalible { get; set; }
    public bool isFavorite { get; set; }
    public int categoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}


Your code shows carId instead of clothesId, could that be the issue?

Please share the CREATE TABLE scripts for all relevant tables.

You need share the model makeup for the OrderDetail and Clothes tables.Besides, if this is one to one relationship you need also check the IdClothes is just one.

Database thinks the ID you are inserting does not exist in the parent table. Usually when a human and a computer are arguing ("But I have opened SSMS and looked in the table, and I can see the parent ID right there, the computer is wrong...") it turns out that the human was looking in the wrong database..

@Sandervan'teinde no, I just accidentally named the string сarID, and overwritten the database, in the OrderDetails model it is called that

@flackoverstow everything is fine with the database, I use the one I work with, I checked it more than once

Hmm, OK.. Well, I've been coding a long time and I can count on zero fingers the number of times a database has told me "there isn't a related primary record with id X" and it's been wrong, so this needs digging into further. Rather than using SSMS to try and look at the data, have you aked the code to retrieve the priary reord by its ID? Did it give it to you? Is the related child record youre saving correct, and definitely has the same ID as its parent in the FK column?

By the way, you don't have to violate C# naming conventions on your props; everything you use, be it an ORM, serializer, mapper etc, will have a way of telling it "this is the name in C#: IsFavourite, but in json/db/whatever, I want you to use 'isFavourite' "

@flackoverstow Okay, I'll check it out, I'll text you, thanks for helping)

Also, I do not recommend you make class names plural; if a class represents a collection suffix its name with ..Collection. Otherwise make class names singular. Make property names singular unless they represent a collection. In your case it seems you may be better calling your class/table Garment - a single item of clothing, then an Order has Garments the custoer bought, a Garment has Orders it appears in and an OrderGarment links the two

@flackoverstow I updated the question, found a strange error, can you take a look please

Why does clothes not have an ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails? Anyway, i think the easiest way to get tit working for you would be: make the tables correct in the DB, with names, IDs, auto increment int PKs, relationships etc, then install EF Core Power Tools visual studio extension, and tell it to reverse engineer the DB. You should end up with a context that Just Works
